# Testing/using a joystick in AppleSoft?

Tags: apple-ii, hardware, applesoft-basic, joystick, hardware-testing

How does one use joysticks in a program on the Apple //?

I have three different joysticks here and I would like to visualize their state (pot and button values), maybe similar to the SDL joystick test, for anyone who's ever seen that.  That seems like it should be fairly easy to do in Applesoft and run real-time enough to see jitter or worn switches.

If the BASIC program is useful more as an exercise than a diagnostic, is there a better tool for testing joysticks?

Comment: `10 PRINT PDL(0),PDL(1):GOTO 10`

Comment: 0 ? PDL(0),PDL(1):RUN

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The paddles and joysticks on the Apple work by charging a capacitor through a variable resistance (potentiometer). For the first joystick, the X-axis corresponds to paddle 0, and the Y-axis to paddle 1, and similarly for the second joystick.

Accessing address $C070 discharges all capacitors, so they can now charge with a speed that is determined by the resistance. Addresses $C064 to $C067 can be read to check if the capacitor is fully charged (MSB set). BASIC is too slow to do that accurately, so you can use the inbuilt `PDL(x)` commands, which call the monitor routine `PREAD`.

The 3 buttons can be read by checking the MSB of addresses $C061 to $C063. In BASIC, you can use the following PEEK commands to get the values.

- PEEK 49249 - PADDLE 0 BUTTON (>127 IF BUTTON PRESSED)
- PEEK 49250 - PADDLE 1 BUTTON (>127 IF BUTTON PRESSED)
- PEEK 49251 - PADDLE 2 BUTTON (>127 IF BUTTON PRESSED)

Here is a simple program:

```
10 LET X = PDL(0)
20 LET Y = PDL(1)
30 PRINT "X=";X;" Y=";Y
40 GOTO 10
```

I've just tested that in AppleWin using the mouse as the joystick and it works fine.

More details about reading the paddles can be found in the appnote [here](http://www.1000bit.it/support/manuali/apple/technotes/aiie/tn.aiie.06.html), which explains some of the quirks you'll need to be aware of.

Comment: Using the PEEKs for the game paddle positions by themselves won't work. Apple paddles are basically potentiometers, to measure them you discharge a capacity through them and measure them time it takes to do so. So you need to access address 49264 ($C070) to start measurement and then poll the "read game paddle" address until the high bit gets set (> 127). BASIC is too slow for that, so use the PDL command as you've done. Buttons work fine as PEEKs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a reason you got rid of the button 3 peek?

Comment: @nevster if you actually managed to attach game paddles or a joystick to the emulator, I'd love to hear which emulator it is.

Comment: The button 3 PEEK was actually the casette input port ($C060), which is not a part of the Apple II game connector. I've never owned an actual analog joystick (only paddles), so it's quite possible they had an extra cable to connect to the cassette input on the back to get a fourth button, or maybe it's a feature of the later Apple models. And I can't remember a program that even uses the third button, so I don't really think it was used anywhere. So it's certainly not canonical.

Comment: Button 3 is only found on the IIgs to my knowledge.

Comment: If you want to read both axes at the same time, try this: http://www.txbobsc.com/aal/1982/aal8203.html#a1

Comment: @MrLister I've definitely managed to use a USB joystick - can't remember if it was on my Windows PC or iMac - I would have been using AppleWin on Windows and Virtual II on Mac.

Comment: Woz implemented this "unconventional" technique to save costs and chip counts.  Instead of implementing a ADC.  Brilliant.