# How do I read the position of an Apple II joystick?

Tags: apple-ii, joystick

Many games on the Apple II supported input from the keyboard, joystick, and [Sirius Joyport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirius_Joyport).  While reading the keyboard and Joyport are straightforward, getting the joystick's position is not.

How does one read the position of the joystick?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The typical Apple II joystick appears to the computer as a pair of analog game
paddles and two buttons.  The easiest way to read the joystick position
is from Applesoft BASIC, using `PDL(n)`.  The process is detailed in [this
post](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/649/56).  The joystick
X axis is `PDL(0)`, the Y axis is `PDL(1)`.

You can do much better with a custom routine.  The reason for this requires
a bit of background.

As explained in [Apple IIe tech note #6](http://www.gno.org/pub/apple2/doc/apple/technotes/aiie/tn.aiie.006),
game paddles are analog devices.  Reading them requires accessing a
memory-mapped I/O location to trigger a capacitor discharge, and then timing
how long it takes for the capacitor to recharge.  The rate at which the
capacitor charges is determined by the position of the paddle or joystick,
which has a variable resistor.

Where things start to get tricky is that each paddle has its own capacitor,
and they all get triggered at once.  If you read the first joystick axis
and then immediately start reading the second, you might catch it in
a state where the capacitor is partially charged, because hitting the
discharge trigger before all capacitors have recharged has no effect.
After reading the first paddle, you have to wait for all paddles to finish
charging before reading another.  This is easy to do, but wastes time.

The monitor `PREAD`
routine, which is used by the Applesoft `PDL(n)` function,
increments a counter every 11 cycles while waiting for the
capacitor to report charged.  The charge time will vary between 2 and 3302
microseconds with ideal hardware, but could vary depending on how close
the electronic components are to their specifications.  256 iterations at
11 cycles per iteration requires (256*11/1.0205) = 2760 microseconds, which
will yield reasonable results for components with +/- 10% tolerance.
(Source: *Understanding the Apple //e*, by Jim Sather, page 7-29.)  The
software handles small variations in the range by reporting 255 for any
large value.

We can save nearly 3 milliseconds by reading both joystick axes
simultaneously.  Unfortunately it's not possible to do that in an 11-cycle
loop on a 6502, which means we're going to lose some resolution.
For many applications this isn't a problem, e.g. many games only care
about up-down-left-right-center.

#### Implementation

The monitor [`PREAD`](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-rom/OrigF8ROM.html#SymPREAD)
function, which reads a single paddle, is straightforward:

```
PTRIG   EQU  $C070
PADDL0  EQU  $C064

PREAD   LDA  PTRIG        TRIGGER PADDLES
        LDY  #$00         INIT COUNT
        NOP               COMPENSATE FOR 1ST COUNT
        NOP
PREAD2  LDA  PADDL0,X     COUNT Y-REG EVERY
        BPL  RTS2D          12 USEC [actually 11]
        INY
        BNE  PREAD2       EXIT AT 255 MAX
        DEY
RTS2D   RTS
```

Jim Sather presented a 22-cycle dual-axis version in *Understanding the Apple //e*:

```
PDL0    EQU  $C064
PDL1    EQU  $C065

DOIT    LDA  PTRIG
        LDX  #0
        LDY  #0
        PHA               GIVE SOME SPACE FOR COUNT = 0
        PLA
GOTPDL1 BIT  $0
CHKPDL0 LDA  PDL0
        BPL  GOTPDL0
        NOP
        INY
        LDA  PDL1
        BMI  NOGOTS
        BPL  GOTPDL1
NOGOTS  INX
        JMP  CHKPDL0

GOTPDL0 BIT  $0
        LDA  PDL1
        BMI  NOGOTS
        RTS
```

He noted that the routine returned a value between 0 and approximately
160.  (In the AppleWin emulator this produces a smooth value from $00 to
$7F, then jumps to $8C at the upper limit.)

John Brooks created an implementation that is a bit longer, but returns values from
$00 to $FF.  See the
listing [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.sys.apple2.programmer/BXExb3dp-yE/D7i_24U5BAAJ).

Another variation can be found in [Stellar 7](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-stellar7/ROCK2.html#SymReadJoystick).  Note the game is only interested in
the 8 principal directions.

#### Notes

Some games that expected input from a game paddle rather than a joystick
would deliberately exit the read loop early.  For example, the paddle
read routine in [Space Eggs](https://6502disassembly.com/a2-space-eggs/SpaceEggs.html)
stops after 105 iterations, because the player's ship can only be in that
many positions.  This allowed the function to execute more quickly with no
loss of precision.  Unfortunately this makes the game a little harder to
play with a joystick, because the joystick's center position (128) is
interpreted as the paddle turned all the way right.

The monitor PREAD function exits when the paddle position has been identified.
This means that an application will execute slightly slower or faster
depending on the current joystick position.  In some cases, a routine that
executes for a fixed amount of time is more useful.

#### Apple IIgs

The Apple IIgs presents an interesting case, because the CPU is faster and
has additional capabilities.
As discussed [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.sys.apple2.programmer/UhPuQRRh4x4/discussion),
there are tricks with the 16-bit accumulator that can be used to examine both
paddle states with one load, allowing one to achieve 11-cycle polling on
both axes.  While it might seem like reading the joystick with the CPU in
"fast mode" would also help, in practice the relationship between cycles
and microseconds is less certain, so switching to 1 MHz mode before reading
paddles is necessary.

The monitor `PREAD` function was updated to work correctly regardless of the
speed setting, so code that calls that -- including Applesoft BASIC -- will
behave consistently.

Some CPU accelerators automatically de-accelerate when the joystick is
read.  For example, the ZipGS could be configured to slow for 5ms when PTRIG
is accessed.